# Цифровая подпись Debug и Release версий android приложения

Tags: android, google-play

Есть приложение к которому привязаны различные `play services`, в частности  `Firebase`, для этого я в `Google Developer Console` зарегестрировал приложение и добавил там Android и Веб-клиент
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 потом в `Firebase Console`  импортировал этот проект там прописаны SHA-1 ключи для `debug` и `release` версий.

Оттуда же я скачал `google-service.json` и добавил себе в приложение.

Вопрос: какой из SHA-1 ключей там должен быть и могут ли там быть оба ключа?

Меня интересует, что если я оставлю там ключ только для `release`  то в дебаг версии(просто запуская приложение с IDE) - этот ключ будет недейстителен, и наоборот -  если я отсавлю ключ в консоли только для дебага - то опубликовав свое приложение в GooglePlay и соответственно подписав его релизным ключем - сервисы работать не будут, потому что в консоли дебаг ключ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы не мешать релизное и отладочное лучше сгенерируйте для каждой конфигурации отдельные `google-service.json` и положите их в соответствующие папки (`src/debug` и `src/release`). Последние версии плей сервис плагина для градла умеют находить этот файл не только в корне проекта, но и в отдельных конфигурациях.

Comment: Я правильно понял: мне в папке src на одном уровне с папкой main  нужно создать еще две папки debug и release  и положить в них разные json?

Comment: да, именно так.

Comment: можите посмотреть другой мой вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/564515/191718 там описано как можно запускать из IDE  конфигурациции debug/release , если я последую  рекомендациям из вашего ответа - оно будет работать?  В смысле что  меняя  build variants будут подтягиваться нужные мне google-service.json

Comment: Да, будут. Плагин гуглосервисов будет генерировать из этих json файлов ресурсы и пихать их в папку с ресерсами соответствующей конфигурации, а дальше при сборке апк ресурсы будут браться из конфигурации которую вы выбрали в build variants

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: А еще вопросик, мне в таком случае в консоли разработчика нужно оба SHA-1 ключа прописать!?

Comment: не знаю, я эту консоль сто лет не видел...

Answer (score 1):

В firebase можно добавлять сколько угодно 'Контрольных сумм сертификатов' SHA-1, так что добавляйте оба.

Comment: Я знаю что их там можно добавлять\удалять\изменять. Меня интересует в переод когда мне нужно дебажить приложение и паралельно заливать релиз версии в Google Play  получаеться что  я иногда подписываю приложение дебаг ключем а когда делаю сборку для Google Play - релиз ключем, то к какому из этих ключей привязываються API  в Developer Console, к примеру Google Drive API