# Можно ли запускать приложение из IDE с подписью release ключем

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Почитал немного документации по `gradle` и [`Android Studio`](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#secure-key). Понял что запуская из IDE нажав на [image: введите сюда описание изображения] мы можем запускать приложение сразу на устройстве в  `debug`-режиме подписанное  отладочным ключем. Меня интересует можно ли запускать таким же образом, `release`  версию подписаную `release`-ным ключем, в смысле не что  бы не генерить `.apk`, а сразу на устройство устанавливать.

Comment: `.apk` всё равно генерируется. Откройте папку `/app/build/output/apk/`

Comment: Каким ключем в таком в случае подписан этот .apk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, можно. Для этого надо:

1. Положить в корень проекта файл с именем `keystore.properties`
2. В нём указать путь к файлу ключа, пароль к нему, алиас и пароль к алиасу

   ```
   storeFile=C://ПУТЬ_К_КЛЮЧУ/KEYSTORE_FILE_NAME.jks
   storePassword=ПАРОЛЬ К КЛЮЧУ
   keyAlias=АЛИАС_КЛЮЧА
   keyPassword=ПАРОЛЬ К АЛИАСУ
   ```
3. Добавьте этот файл в `.gitignore` чтобы он не улетел в удалённый репозиторий
4. Теперь в `build.gradle` модуля (не основной `build.gradle`, а тот, где зависимости, версия, пакет приложения etc) надо загрузить указанный выше файл и получить из него значения. После чего эти значения надо задать в блоке `signingConfigs` для `release` варианта сборки и в `buildTypes` для релизного варианта указать эту конфигурацию подписывания. Итоговый  `build.gradle` будет выглядеть примерно так:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

   // Load keystore
   def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file("keystore.properties");
   def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
   keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))

   android {
       lintOptions {
           checkReleaseBuilds false
       }
       signingConfigs {
           release {
               storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
               storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
               keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
               keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           }
       }
       compileSdkVersion 23
       buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

       defaultConfig {
           applicationId "ru.example"
           minSdkVersion 15
           targetSdkVersion 23
           versionCode 1
           versionName "1.0"
       }
       buildTypes {
           release {
               minifyEnabled false
               //указываем конфигурацию подписывания
               signingConfig signingConfigs.release
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
           }
       }
   }

   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
       compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
       compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'

   }
   ```
5. Теперь вы сможете выбирать вариант `release` сборки приложения из `buildVariants` вкладки студии (панелька слева, внизу, сбоку) и ваше приложение будет устанавливаться на девайс будучи подписанным релизным ключом когда вы как обычно запустите `Run`

Comment: Хорошо, все сделал, судя по тому что все работает устанавливается release версия, т.е. мне теперь перед тем как нажать на кнопку 'Run' нужно просто в 'build variants' выбрать нужный конфиг? и еще в момент исполнения приложения могу каким то образом узнать релиз это или дебаг?

Comment: и еще в signingConfigs  мне нужно добавлять debug config  меня там щас только release как в вашем примере

Comment: Да, просто выбираетеинужный вариант. Узнать, вроде, можно чрез Build.Config. А дебаг гонфиг для подписки дебажным ключом не нужен. Он по дефолту сразу есть