# Android logcat не работает

Tags: android, android-sdk, gradle, логирование, logcat

Отлаживаю приложение через USB, Android Studio не пишет ничего в logcat. Раньше все было отлично, но сейчас вообще не идет никакой информации даже если убрать фильтры. Копался в Функциях для разработчиков на смартфоне, ничего не нашел.

вот это я нашел:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас случаем не релизная сборка?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, недавно сделал, чтобы гугл авторизацию начать делать. Это могло повлиять?

Comment: Как раз в этом и дело

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы запускаете релизную сборку приложения, то у вас, скорее всего, не прописано в `gradle` `debuggable true` для неё.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable true
    }
}
```

Второй вариант включения логов в релизной сборке - указать этот атрибут в манифесте через атрибут тега `Application`

```
android:debuggable="true"
```

Самый же лучший вариант - настроить варианты для сборки так, чтобы иметь возможность включать/выключать логи для релизной сборки в разных оной вариантах так:

```
buildTypes {

    debug {
        resValue "bool", "debuggable", "true"
    }

    release {
    }
}


productFlavors {

    dev {
        resValue "bool", "debuggable", "true"
    }

    prod {
        resValue "bool", "debuggable", "false"
    }
}
```

В манифесте укажите ссылку на сгенерированный градлом ресурс:

```
android:debaggable="@bool/debuggable"
```

Теперь вы сможете собирать `devRelease` сборку с включёнными логами и `prodRelease` с выключенными. А `debug` сборки всегда будут с включёнными логами

Comment: огромное спасибо!)

Comment: блин, пришел домой, попробовал, что-то не получилось, добавил debuggable true в свой release buildType, но логи не идут

Comment: @Maxgmer, как я понял из правки дело было в моей опечатке?

Comment: к сожалению нет, не знаю, в чем причина, прописал в релиз debuggable true в gradle, но не помогло

Comment: начал копаться, у меня был выбран build variant debug, поставил на release, вообще нельзя запустить приложение, вот скриншот, прикрепляю выше. Когда жму на Fix и прикрепляю конфигурацию ничего не меняется вообще, та же ошибка и та же кнопка Fix.

Comment: @Maxgmer, т.е. у вас и раньше была не релизная сборка и в дебажной тоже нет логов?.. А собрать релизную вы не можете, т.к. у вас нет конфигурации подписывания для релиза. Вот тут написано как это сделать: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/564515/17609

Comment: я без понятия что мне делать, ничего не помогает, в логах приложения пусто, в No Filters после запуска что-то пишет до определенного момента, потом затихает.

Comment: может в этом и проблема? в No Filters в последней строке всегда пишет read: unexpected EOF! до затихания. Написано не красным цветом, поэтому не обращал внимания

Comment: о боже мой,  получилось!! Спустя 4 часа! Я просто нажал на мусорный бак слева в меню logcat'a! Прошу прощение за кучу потраченного на меня времени! Не знаю, что делает этот мусорный бак, но он меня спас!))

Comment: @Maxgmer, эта кнопка просто очищает консоль от всего, что в неё выведено. Наверное у вас очень много логов и они что-то засоряют. Видимо вам таки надо просто регулярно чистить)

Comment: никогда такого не было, может это баг студии какой-то) просто не выводило только по фильтру приложения

Comment: @Maxgmer, это мог быть да, глюк студии. А могла быть и опечатка в фильтре. Например пробел не в том месте потавишь и всё - в логах пусто)

Answer (score 1):

Включите это в Android Studio:

**Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB Integration**