# Как подключить LogCat при отладке по USB в Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Добрый день.

Не могу нигде найти внятный ответ. 
Как подключить LogCat при отладке по USB в Android Studio?

Comment: alt-6 попробуйте

Comment: Вы не знаете где его открыть в Android Studio? Или он у вас не работает? Немного не ясно.

Comment: или тут может по теме - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583256/android-logcat-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82?rq=1

Answer (score 6):

идеальном мире, в котором безусловно живет большинство посетителей сего чудесного ruSO для "подключения" LogCat ничего не нужно делать, ну максимум ткнуть мышкой на  вкладку LogCat, в левом нижнем углу Android Studio или же нажать на клавиатуре волшебную комбинацию *Alt-6*

Если ваш мир неидеален, то ни то ни другое не поможет и вы увидите пустое окно LogCat. По большому счету причин может быть 3:

1. У вас проблема с USB драйвером вашего устройства - тогда вам прямиком к сайту производителя телефона
2. На телефоне не активирован режим разработчика - в этом случае утыкайтесь в мануал телефоне и почитайте как активировать режим разработчика
3. Далее идут всякие экзотические причины, как то отсутствие ADB или его неправильная версия, всевозможные злокозненные антивирусы и проч. ерунда.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась установкой универсального драйвера для MTK

Answer (score 0):

Часто сталкивался с такой же проблемой. Хотел дать возможность тестировщикам читать логи (сам проект при этом собирать не требовалось). Выяснилось, что без успешной синхронизации gradle вкладка logcat не появляется.