# некорректная работа checkbox android

Tags: android, android-studio, checkbox, android-style

пытаюсь изменить цвет флажка и квадратика checkbox на свой, но при создании своего стиля и подключение его к флажку приложения слетает как только я касаюсь флажка. может где-то не так подключаю стиль или не так сам стиль написан??
Код стиля:

```
<style name="red_check" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF0000</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">28sp</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
```

Код activity_main.xml:

```
<CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/red"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"
            android:text="Red"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize = "26sp"
            android:theme="@style/red_check"/>
```

Вставляю код ошибки если я правильно понял что это:

```
02-27 14:32:10.618 31349-31349/com.example.andrew.mm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       Process: com.example.andrew.mm, PID: 31349
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected receiver of type com.example.andrew.mm.MainActivity, but got android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:4466)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5232)
                                                                           at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:122)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21289)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

Comment: А без стиля не слетает? Добавьте стектрейс ошибки в вопрос.

Comment: а как их добавить? я же на телефоне тестирую, ну то есть я телефон подключил по кабелю и пробую

Comment: Стектрейсы берутся из [LogCat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775173/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-logcat-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-usb-%D0%B2-android-studio), вне зависимости эмулятор это или реальное устройство, подключенное по кабелю, вай фай...

Comment: Проблема в вашем методе `onCheckboxClicked`. Уберите его из xml. Клики для чекбокса обрабатываются по другому. На CheckBox вешается метод `onCheckedChangeListener` в коде.

Comment: а можно как-то сделать для трех чекбоксов один обработчик, или нужно отдельно для каждого?? потому-что я этот метод писал для трех чекбоксов сразу

Comment: Да, можно один обработчик для трёх чекбоксов. Там внутрь метода придёт `CompoundButton buttonView` - тот чекбокс, с которым взаимодействовали.