# Обновление приложения Android

Tags: java, android, цифровая-подпись

Создал свое первое приложение под Android. На настоящем устройстве после установки, если я хочу скачать с компьютера и установить другую версию, телефон мне выдает что-то типа: "Пакет с таким названием уже существует конфликт подписей". Вроде подписку создал как по инструкции. Может я чего то не знаю?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Приложение уникально идентифицируется по пакету и ключу подписи.

В вашем случае, видимо, вы на девайсе имеете приложение, подписанное релизным ключом (скачено из маркета), а с компа ставите подписанное дебажным ключом. Засим и конфликт подписей приложений с одинаковым пакетом, но разными ключами.

Вам надо или снести приложение с телефона или подписывать в студии, при сборке, APK релизным ключом.

Вот так можно подписывать приложение релизный ключом:
[Можно ли запускать приложение из IDE с подписью release ключем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/564515/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-ide-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C%D1%8E-release-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC/564538#564538)

Comment: пример если есть

Comment: Добавил ссылку на ответ

Comment: не помогло может есть другой вариант

Comment: @user8978194, не могло не помочь. Наверное вы что-то не так делаете. В крайнем случае просто удалите вручную приложение с телефона.

Comment: я то удалю но потом если выставлю в плей маркет и потом выпущу обновления у юзеров такая же херня будет?

Comment: Нет, такого не должно будет случиться, т.к. приложение будет с одинаковой подписью. С разной подписью нельзя будет апдейт в маркет выложить.